# How to use ProcMon on Windows XP - Get an error about InitializeSRWLock

Tags: windows-xp, procmon

When running procmon on Windows XP Pro SP3 I get this error:

> Procmon.exe - Entry Point Not Found 
> The procedure entry point
>   InitializeSRWLock could not be located in the dynamic link library
>   KERNEL32.dll.

Is there a version for XP specifically?

Answer (score 14):

It seems that the ProcMon from May 13, 2014 version 3.10 works on XP.

Available for download from the Archive.org site: https://web.archive.org/web/20140625080651/http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx

Comment: Direct link to ProcMon v3.10: https://web.archive.org/web/20140627132742/http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip

Answer (score 5):

According to David D C e Freitas.
I find that the last version that supports XP is **3.20**:

Well, I find that I have no reputation to send multiple url links to.

Process Monitor v3.20(XP+,2015.5.26,2015.6.11)
https://web.archive.org/web/20150629015501/https://live.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessMonitor.zip
https://web.archive.org/web/20150603092645/https://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip
..
..
..
hxxps://web.archive.org/web/20160710022710/hxxps://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip
Process Monitor v3.30(Vista+,2016.7.24)
hxxps://web.archive.org/web/20160805090321/hxxps://download.sysinternals.com/files/SysinternalsSuite.zip
Process Monitor v3.40(Vista+,2017.9.26)
hxxps://web.archive.org/web/20170926161141/hxxps://live.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessMonitor.zip

hxxps=https

---

Add(2019.12):
**The new version 3.5X has removed the InitializeSRWLock function reference and re-supported XP/2003**.

Please download the latest version from the official website to try.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Version 3.20 did not work on my XP Pro SP3 machine, but version 3.10 did.

Comment: @dougwoodrow: The new version 3.5X has removed the InitializeSRWLock function reference and re-supported XP/2003.
Please download the latest version from the official website to try.

Comment: Just a heads up, I tried v3.53  on XP SP3 it worked fine but on XP SP2 but caused blue screen crash - it could be just me.